# sed: delete previous line

Tags: regex, sed

I need to remove a blank line prior to a match.

So given the file:

```
random text
more random text






#matchee
```

I need to match the pattern /#matchee/, then delete the blank line before it.

Here's what I've tried --- no success:

```
sed '/^[ \t]*$/{N;/#matchee.*$/{D;}}' file.txt
```

My logic:

- If blank line; append next line to pattern space yielding /blank line\n...etc/
- If pattern space contains /#matchee/, Delete up to newline yielding /#matchee/

Basically /matchee/ is a constant that must be maintained and I need to remove an extra
blank line from each record in a file of records delimited by /#matchee/.

This produces no effect whatever. I am RTFM-ing and `D`  is supposed to delete pattern
space up to the newline. Since `N` appends a newline plus next line --- this should produce the desired results ....alas ....no and no again. Is this because the match contains essentially nothing ( blankline )?

Comment: @deathApril: `/` delimits the regex. In this case, the regexes are `^[ \t]*$` and `#matchee.*$`. (And this is fundamentally a `sed` problem. Mere knowledge of regexes will not help.)

Comment: oh.. too bad you can't do a simple regex replace of `/\s+(\n[ \t]*#matchee)/` with the first capturing group `\1` :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach will work if there are an odd number of blank lines, but it will fail if there are an even number. Your `sed` script is a loop of the following.

- grab a line *L1*, and add it to the pattern space
- if *L1* is non-blank, print it; but if it *is* blank, then:

  - grab another line, *L2*, and add it to the pattern space
  - if *L2* contains `#matchee`, discard *L1* from the pattern space
  - print the pattern space, which is consists either of *L1* and *L2*, or just of *L2*

You'll notice that *L2* is always printed, even if it's blank and followed by a line that contains `#matchee`. It's protected by the fact that it immediately follows an odd number of blank lines.

**Edited to add:** To fix the above-described problem, you can add an inner loop by using the `:` command to create a label and the `b` command to "branch" to it (goto). This:

```
sed '/^[ \t]*$/{: a;N;/#matchee/!P;D;/^[ \t]*$/b a}' file.txt
```

is a loop of the following:

- grab a line *L1*, and add it to the pattern space
- if *L1* is non-blank, print it; but if it *is* blank, then:

  - create label `a` ← this is a no-op, just a place to `goto`
  - grab another line, *L2*, and add it to the pattern space
  - if *L2* does *not* contain `#matchee`, print *L1*
  - discard *L1* from the pattern space (whether or not we printed it)
  - we can now think of *L2* as *L1*; it's the only thing in the pattern space
  - if the rechristened *L1* is blank, `goto a`

Comment: Thanks ruakh -- pure genius! It's going to take me 3 days to figure out how it works exactly ...but brilliant nonetheless.

Comment: @Bubnoff: You're welcome! But instead of figuring this out, I'd almost recommend you just rewrite it in a less crazy language. Sed is just so *hard*, whereas this would be trivial to write in (say) Perl.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
sed '$!N;s/^\s*\n\(#matchee.*\)/\1/;P;D' file.txt
```

to follow how it works run this:

```
sed '$!N;l;s/^\s*\n\(#matchee.*\)/\1/;P;D' file.txt
```

N.B. `P` prints upto the first newline, `D` deletes upto the first newline and starts a new cycle without reading in another record unless there is no newline, in which case it behaves like `d` and reads in a line and begins the next cycle.

Comment: Works! What does this part do: `$!` ?

Comment: `$!N` means if not the last record get the next. `$` means last record, `!` negates the action and `N` read in next record.